# How to prevent hotlinking of flv files?

Tags: php, firefox, .htaccess, flv, http-referer

How to, using PHP and/or .htaccess prevent hotlinking?

There's a site, which is allowed to access the flv files located on my server, however I've noticed that there are many requests from other domains as well...

Here's the actual rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://alloweddomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .flv denied.php [NC,L]
```

It's working OK except for Firefox, because FF is not sending referrer info when accessing .flv files...

Answer (score 3):

Add a condition for blank referrers:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://alloweddomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .flv denied.php [NC,L]
```

http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/ is a good place to start.

Comment: .. or make it an alternative condition `^$` with `[OR]`

Comment: Correct. If that is not included, AND is implicitly used.

Comment: Adding this condition above your provided code will allow Firefox to view the FLV files.

Comment: Ah, in that case, remove the `!` from the beginning. That is the `not` symbol. I was confusing myself.

Answer (score 0):

Also allow requests with no referrer at all. Some firewalls also block referrers.